# How to read a large IEnumerable<> fast

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have the following code returning 22,000,000 records from the database pretty quick:

```
var records = from row in dataContext.LogicalMapTable
                          select
                              new
                              {
                                  row.FwId,
                                  row.LpDefId,
                                  row.FlDefMapID
                              };
```

The code following the database call above takes over 60 seconds to run:

```
var cache = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var record in records)
{
   var tempHashCode = record.FirmwareVersionID + "." + record.LogicalParameterDefinitionID;

   cache.Add(tempHashCode, record.FirmwareLogicalDefinitionMapID);
}

return cache;
```

Is there a better way to do this with improve performance?

Comment: I suspect the actual execution is taking longer than you expect. Because the first statement is only an expression and does not really execute anything. As soon as you begin to iterate over the 'expression' in `foreach()` the actual query is executed on the server.

Comment: Not really, apart from finding a different hash than your computed one. The real question you should be asking is: Do I *really REALLY* need 22,000,000 items in my cache?

Comment: 366,666 records per second is a pretty darn good speed for any RDBMS. Anything above 100,000 rows per second is fast. Your best choice is to read less data, whatever that may mean in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your code is not slow. It just causes LINQ query evaluation, you can see this by consuming your query earlier, for example

```
var records = (from row in dataContext.LogicalMapTable
                          select
                              new
                              {
                                  row.FwId,
                                  row.LpDefId,
                                  row.FlDefMapID
                              }).ToList();
```

So it is your LINQ query that is slow, and here is how you can fix it.

You probably don't need 22M records cached in memory. Things you can try:

- Pagination (take, skip)
- Change queries to include specific ids or other columns. E.g. before `select * ...`, after `select * ... where id in (1,2,3) ...`
- Do most of the analytic work at database, it's fast and doesn't take up your app memory
- Prefer queries that bring small data batches fast. You can run several of these concurrently to update different bits of your UI

Comment: As said by oleski - "The second part of your code is not slow. It just causes LINQ query evaluation, you can see this by consuming your query earlier"  [See deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in comments, reading the entire list like that is very inefficient.

Based on the code you posted, I am assuming that after the list is loaded into your "Cache", you lookup the FirmwareLogicalDefinitionMapID using the Key of FirmwareVersionID + "." + LogicalParameterDefinitionID;

My suggestion to improve overall performance and memory usage is to implement an actual caching pattern, something like this:

```
public static class CacheHelper
{
    public static readonly object _SyncLock = new object();
    public static readonly _MemoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public static int GetFirmwareLogicalDefinitionMapID(int firmwareVersionID, int logicalParameterDefinitionID)
    {
        int result = -1;

        // Build up the cache key
        string cacheKey = string.Format("{0}.{1}", firmwareVersionID, logicalParameterDefinitionID);

        // Check if the object is in the cache already
        if(_MemoryCache.Countains(cacheKey))
        {
            // It is, so read it and type cast it
            object cacheObject = _MemoryCache[cacheKey];

            if(cacheObject is int)
            {
                result = (int)cacheObject;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The object is not in cache, aquire a sync lock for thread safety         
            lock(_SyncLock)
            {
                // Double check that the object hasnt been put into the cache by another thread.
                if(!_MemoryCache.Countains(cacheKey))
                {
                    // Still not there, now Query the database
                    result = (from i in dataContext.LogicalMapTable
                              where i.FwId == firmwareVersionID && i.LpDefId == logicalParameterDefinitionID
                              select i.FlDefMapID).FirstOrDefault();

                     // Add the results to the cache so that the next operation that asks for this object can read it from ram
                    _MemoryCache.Add(new CacheItem(cacheKey, result), new CacheItemPolicy() { SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) });
                }
                else
                {
                    // we lost a concurrency race to read the object from source, its in the cache now so read it from there.
                    object cacheObject = _MemoryCache[cacheKey];
                    if(cacheObject is int)
                    {
                        result = (int)cacheObject;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // return the results
        return result;
    }
}
```

You should also read up on the .Net MemoryCache: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net-4-0

Hope this helps!